# What is the Impact of compatibility level on stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, compatibility

I am currently using SSMS version 17.8.1
The database that I am working with currently shows me the compatibility level of 110. I have various stored procedures running on this every day.
Now to improve performance, I wanted to update my database's compatibility level to 140.
I want to know if this would lead to any error with the current running of stored procs.

I am still researching the negatives of updating compatibility level but have much clarity. I have looked at other similar questions on StackOverflow but I am specifically looking for answers in terms of the above specific version and compatibility levels

My main aim is to gain performance by updating the compatibility level

Comment: The [fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017#differences-between-lower-compatibility-levels-and-level-120) describes the differences from 110 to 120, and you can make your way upwards from there to review all the other changes. Also read the rest of the page; it will point you to the [Data Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=53595), for example. In general, the chance of things outright breaking is small, but you can definitely observe performance changes.

Comment: What makes you think that simply updating the compatibility level will improve performance?

Comment: @JeroenMostert - Thank you. I have a follow-up question. As per this [link]( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level?view=sql-server-2017), it looks like SSMS 17+ supports capability from 100 to 140. Couldn't I directly make the change to 140, or is it recommended that I move with small steps by updating it to 120, then 130 and later to 140?

Comment: Either way is viable. If you want to do a small change because you aren't expecting any changes in your database and you won't want to make use of new features, you can do that; if you want to go to the latest compat level so all features are available, you can do that. Either way you need a solid picture of what could possibly break *before* you change it. Note that optimizer changes from one compat level to another can easily be *detrimental* for your particular workload; higher compat level != automatic better performance. One you've managed the risk, you still need to test.